# Can I save Amazon Lex log and metrics data in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lex

Is there any way to store Amazon Lex log and metrics data in an Amazon S3 bucket?

Answer (score 2):

As of a few weeks ago, you can now save Lex text conversation logs to CloudWatch Logs (text bot), and audio conversation logs to S3.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/using-amazon-lex-conversation-logs-to-monitor-and-improve-interactions/

As usual, metrics can be exported with the GetMetricData API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html

Answer (score 2):

To turn on logs using the console

1. Open the Amazon Lex console https://console.aws.amazon.com/lex.
2. From the list, choose a bot.
3. Choose the Settings tab, and then from the left menu choose
   Conversation logs.
4. In the list of aliases, choose the settings icon for the alias for
   which you want to configure conversation logs.
5. Select whether to log text, audio, or both.
6. For text logging, enter the Amazon CloudWatch Logs log group name.
7. For audio logging, enter the S3 bucket information.
8. Optional. To encrypt audio logs, choose the AWS KMS key to use for
   encryption.
9. Choose an IAM role with the required permissions.
10. Choose Save to start logging conversations.